# How to make a multi-step android view?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to make a multi-step register page. but i just need the pages. I lave tried many things but i don't know how to connect the register parts together to submit them all to the server at the same time but i think making multiple activity is not that efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a ViewPager. Here is how it is used.

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html